# Set z index on table cell div for each row in angular material

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material

I'm trying to set z index/overlayed div on each row's cell which is having expandable effect on icon click.

Issue here is it(icons) expands column even I gave z-index for overlaying it over other(left side) columns instead. Expectation here is it shouldn't expand column width, instead of that it should overlay left side for every icons.

[Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-u16asn) is StackBlitz for the same where it is expanding column.

[image: Expectation]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The functionality you are asking for can be achieved using the css `position` property.

we can wrap symbols in a div which is having css `position:absolute` and the parent div with the class `button-row` can have css `position:relative`.

I have updated your stackblitz demo as explained above.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackoverflow-56936645

your template will look like:

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="symbol">
  <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Symbol</th>
  <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element; let i = index">
    <!--.button-row starts, it is a parent row with position relative-->
    <div class="button-row" style="">
      <!--.float-button-container starts,  it is a wrapper div with position:absolute-->
      <div class="float-button-container" [class.active]="showFloatingButtons[i] == true">
        <mat-icon mat-fab color="primary" class="floating-buttons">offline_pin
        </mat-icon>
        <mat-icon mat-fab color="primary" class="floating-buttons">query_builder
        </mat-icon>
        <mat-icon mat-fab color="primary" class="floating-buttons" disabled>restore
        </mat-icon>
        <mat-icon mat-fab color="primary" class="floating-buttons">
          play_circle_filled
        </mat-icon>
      </div>
      <!--.float-button-container ends-->
      <mat-icon (click)="toggleFloat(i)" class="sky_blue">more_horiz</mat-icon>
    </div>
    <!--.button-row ends-->
  </td>
</ng-container>
```

and your styles will look like:

```
.button-row {
  position: relative;
}

.float-button-container {
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  transform: translateX(-100%);
  background-color: #ffffff;
  width: 0px;
  transition: width 150ms ease-in-out;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.float-button-container.active {
  width: 100px;
  transition: width 150ms ease-in-out;
}
```

Your problem is almost similar like making a dropdown which opens at the left side.
Read more about making dropdowns using css here : https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_dropdowns.asp

I hope this will help.

Comment: Awesome I was just about to give up on this but you saved me.

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with z-index.
If you want your column to have a set width, set its `width` CSS property to a fixed value!

Comment: It seems you didn't go through whole question. What I am trying here is it shouldn't expand column width. So Instead of that it should be rendered at left side(Over weight column).

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. You want your icons to display, not from left to right, but from right to left, overlaid over what's on the left column?

Comment: Yep all icons should be overlaid over left column which is titled as weight.

Answer (score 0):

This problem can be solved by creating a css class and adding it to the first `mat-icon` in your `ng-container`.

The css class that you can use is:

```
    .fb1
    {
       margin-left:-6rem;
       margin-top:.3rem;
    }
```

And you should add it to this element.

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="symbol">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Symbol </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element; let i = index">
        <div [ngClass]="showFloatingButtons[i] == true ? 'floating-pane-active' : 
'floating-pane-deactive'" class="button-row" style="">        

<!--Css Class fb1 added below-->
            <mat-icon mat-fab *ngIf="showFloatingButtons[i]== true" color="primary" 
class="floating-buttons fb1">offline_pin
            </mat-icon>
<!--Css Class fb1 added above-->

            <mat-icon mat-fab *ngIf="showFloatingButtons[i] == true" color="primary" class="floating-buttons fb2">query_builder
            </mat-icon>
            <mat-icon mat-fab *ngIf="showFloatingButtons[i] == true" color="primary" class="floating-buttons " disabled>restore
            </mat-icon>
            <mat-icon mat-fab *ngIf="showFloatingButtons[i] == true" color="primary" class="floating-buttons ">
                play_circle_filled</mat-icon>
            <mat-icon (click)="toggleFloat(i)" class="sky_blue">more_horiz</mat-icon>
        </div>
    </td>
</ng-container>
```

Please note that the text will start to overlap on smaller screen sizes so you may want to use Javascript to hide the text of the Weight column and/or reposition the symbol column further when the button is clicked on smaller screen sizes.